# Python indentation lost in minted when export to bearmer/latex in orgmode

Tags: indentation, minted, org-mode

I have a strange problem when exporting to beamer in org-mode. I use minted to export python. But for a reason I don't understand, I lost sometime the indentation. 
For instance:

```
** NDVI is SciPy 1/2
Since operations on array are  element-wise, the computation of the
NDVI is really simple.

#+BEGIN_SRC python :exports code
 import scipy as sp
 #def compute_ndvi(im,r=3,ir=4):
 '''
 The function computes the NVDI of an image.

 Parameters
 ----------
 im: the image cube
 r: the indice of the band that corresponds to the red
 ir: the indice of the band that corresponds to the infrared

 Returns
 -------
 ndvi: the NDVI, an float-array
 '''
 [nl,nc,nb]=im.shape
 if nb <2:
     print "Two bands are needed to compute the NDVI"
     return None

 else:
     ndvi = (im[:,:,ir-1]-im[:,:,r-1])/(im[:,:,ir-1]+im[:,:,r-1])
     return ndvi
#+END_SRC
```

will produce the correct output
[image]

But if I uncomment the definition of the function:

```
import scipy as sp
def compute_ndvi(im,r=3,ir=4):
    '''
    The function computes the NVDI of an image.

    Parameters
    ----------
    im: the image cube
    r: the indice of the band that corresponds to the red
    ir: the indice of the band that corresponds to the infrared

    Returns
    -------
    ndvi: the NDVI, an float-array
    '''
    [nl,nc,nb]=im.shape
    if nb <2:
        print "Two bands are needed to compute the NDVI"
        return None
    else:
        ndvi = (im[:,:,ir-1]-im[:,:,r-1])/(im[:,:,ir-1]+im[:,:,r-1])
        return ndvi
```

The output is not correct
[image]

The file generated by babel is fine for each case and compiling the tex generated by org mode width pdflatex gave the same results.

My ini.el is as follow:

```
 ;; Org mode and bearmer export
(require 'org-install)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org\\'" . org-mode))
(setq system-time-locale "C")
(define-key global-map "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
(define-key global-map "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
(setq org-log-done t)
(setq org-agenda-files (list "~/Documents/Org_Files/todo.org"))

(require 'ox-beamer)
(setq org-latex-to-pdf-process 
  '("pdflatex --shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
"pdflatex --shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
"pdflatex --shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))


(defun my-beamer-bold (contents backend info)
 (when (eq backend 'beamer)
  (replace-regexp-in-string "\\`\\\\[A-Za-z0-9]+" "\\\\textbf" contents)))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-bold-functions 'my-beamer-bold)

(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((python . t)
  (latex . t)))
(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)
(setq org-babel-python-command "ipython --pylab --pdb --nosep --classic --no-banner --no-confirm-exit")

(setq org-latex-listings 'minted)
(setq org-latex-minted-options
   '(("fontsize" "\\footnotesize")("bgcolor" "black")("obeytabs" "true")))

(require 'ox-latex)
(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)
(setq org-latex-pdf-process
   '("pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
    "pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o   %f"
"pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))
```

I don't understand why I lose the formating. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

Ok I found the solution, I need to add the folowing in the init.el

```
(setq org-src-preserve-indentation t)
```

Found [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/81817)